# Jquery-Break setInterval and reset to its original position

Tags: jquery, html

When I press Stop, I need the animation to stop and return to its orignal position (starting point). So far I am only able to pause the animation.

My Jquery

```
var timer;

    $(document).ready(function () {

        $('#start').click(function () {
            timer = setInterval(function () {
                $("#animate").animate({ 'marginLeft': '200px' }, 400)
                $("#animate").animate({ 'marginTop': '200px' }, 400)
                $("#animate").animate({ 'marginLeft': '10px' }, 400)
                $("#animate").animate({ 'marginTop': '0px' }, 400)
                console.log('Success');
            }, 100);

        });
        $("#stop").click(function () {
            clearInterval(timer);
            console.log('Trigger!!');
        });
    });
```

[My Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cgy5k4j6/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have correct code, the problem is with timing, you can see that you have applied 400 millisecond to each animation, and its interval to just 100 millisecond, so animation function is calling too many times in a one second.

> **Solution**: 
>   Just increase interval time to 2000 millisecond to stop animation. or more then (400 X 4 =1600)

```js
var timer;

$(document).ready(function () {

    $('#start').click(function () {
        timer = setInterval(function () {
            $("#animate").animate({ 'marginLeft': '200px' }, 400)
            $("#animate").animate({ 'marginTop': '200px' }, 400)
            $("#animate").animate({ 'marginLeft': '10px' }, 400)
            $("#animate").animate({ 'marginTop': '0px' }, 400)
            console.log('Success');
        }, 2000);

    });
    $("#stop").click(function () {
        clearInterval(timer);
        console.log('Trigger!!');
    });
});
```

```css
body {
    border: 1px solid blue;
    width: 237px;
    height: 263px;
}

div {
    margin: 7px;
    width: 40px;
    height: 40px;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0px;
    top: 30px;
    background: lightgreen;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button id="start">Start</button>
<button id="stop">Stop</button>
<div id="animate"></div>
```

Extra note :

You can use jquery chain to all 4 step into one for less coding:

```
$("#animate").animate({ 'marginLeft': '200px' }, 400).animate({ 'marginTop': '200px' }, 400).animate({ 'marginLeft': '10px' }, 400).animate({ 'marginTop': '0px' }, 400);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code.

```
var intervalId;
var flag = false;
var a = function() { 
   $("#animate").animate({ 'marginLeft': '200px' }, 400)
                $("#animate").animate({ 'marginTop': '200px' }, 400)
                $("#animate").animate({ 'marginLeft': '10px' }, 400)
                $("#animate").animate({ 'marginTop': '0px' }, 400, function(){
        if(!$(this).is('animated') && flag === true){
              $("#animate").removeAttr("style");
        }
    })
}

$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#start").click(function(){
            flag = false;
            intervalId = setInterval(a,1000);
    });

    $("#stop").click(function(){
            flag = true;
        clearInterval(intervalId);
    });

});
```

You can check when the last animation is completed and set a flag true. when the flag is true and animation is completed simply remove the style attribute of the div. Set the flag false again when you start the new animation.

Here is a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/SmitRaval/cgy5k4j6/25/)

Let me know if it works for you or not.